# Posting an array using Titanium HttpClient

Tags: titanium-mobile

I am trying to post to a webservice using Titanium HttpClient like so:

```
var non_data = {
        user_id: Facebook_ID,
        "friends_ids[0]":friendIds[0],
        "friends_ids[1]":friendIds[1]


    };

    var non_xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload: function(){
            Titanium.API.info('Status: ' + this.status);
            Titanium.API.info('ResponseText: ' + this.responseText);
            Titanium.API.info('connectionType: ' + this.connectionType);
            Titanium.API.info('location: ' + this.location);
            alert("Get_Non_Friends response: " +this.responseText);
        }
    });

    non_xhr.open('POST', myURL);
    non_xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    non_xhr.send(non_data);
```

But it doesn't seem to be getting the array elements right. Can anyone tell how to post and array of params.

Also I found a post on TIMOB that says to do something like this, which I am currently trying:

```
non_xhr.open('POST', myURL);
    //non_xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    non_xhr.send('user_id=someData&friends_ids[0]=someData);
```

Can anyone tell me the best approach for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the send method. The send method should be something like this

```
non_xhr.send({paramName : non_data});
```

The paramName is the name which is required by the web service. Ex

```
non_xhr.send({
file: abc.jpg
```

});

Also its advised to have onerror method too just like onload method.